# How to find pointer errors?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I am attempting learn C by creating a Chess playing AI. When I try to free some memory and I accidentally free some memory that I am using.

I ran the program through valgrind so I can see where the memory errors are but I don't see why the memory is being freed. I am running on a ubuntu variation (PopOS!).

This is the code that generates possible moves and picks one I belive the error is in here near the while loops with the tempOut->next variable.

```
void initDataSet()
{

    printf("Starting Data init\n");
    setupBoard(currentBoard->board);
    currentBoard->parent = 0;
    currentBoard->children = 0;
    findPossibleMoves(1, currentBoard); //aiutils.c:189
    depth++;
    struct boardStateList* temp[6];
    int isAITurn[6];
    int bestValue[6];

    int count = 0;
    struct boardStateList* counter = currentBoard->children;

    while(counter)
    {
        count++;
        counter = counter->next;
    }


    for(int i = 0;i < 6;i++)
        if(((depth + i)% 2) == isAIWhite)
        {
            isAITurn[i] = 1; 
        }
        else
        {
            isAITurn[i] = 0;
        }
        int turn = 1;
    temp[0] = currentBoard->children;
            bestValue[0] = (depth - 1) % 2 == isAIWhite ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;    
        while(temp[0])
        {
            printf("calc Move %d out of %d\n", turn++, count);

            bestValue[1] = (depth) % 2 == isAIWhite ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;  
            findPossibleMoves((depth % 2), temp[0]->element);
            temp[1] = temp[0]->element->children;
            while(temp[1])
            {
                bestValue[2] = (depth + 1) % 2 == isAIWhite ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;  
                findPossibleMoves(((depth + 1) % 2), temp[1]->element);
                temp[2] = temp[1]->element->children;
                while(temp[2])
                {
                    bestValue[3] = (depth + 2) % 2 == isAIWhite ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;  
                    findPossibleMoves(((depth + 2) % 2), temp[2]->element);
                    temp[3] = temp[2]->element->children;
                    while(temp[3])
                    {
                        bestValue[4] = (depth + 3) % 2 == isAIWhite ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;  
                        findPossibleMoves(((depth + 3) % 2), temp[3]->element);
                        temp[4] = temp[3]->element->children;
                        while(temp[4])
                        {
                            bestValue[5] = (depth + 4) % 2 == isAIWhite ? INT_MIN : INT_MAX;  
                            findPossibleMoves(((depth + 4) % 2),temp[4]->element);
                            temp[5] = temp[4]->element->children;
                            while(temp[5])
                            {
                                temp[5]->element->boardValue = evaluateBoard(temp[5]->element->board, isAIWhite);
                                if((depth + 4) % 2 == isAIWhite ? temp[5]->element->boardValue > bestValue[5] : temp[5]->element->boardValue < bestValue[5])
                                    bestValue[5] = temp[5]->element->boardValue;
                                temp[5] = temp[5]->next;    
                            }
                            temp[4]->element->boardValue = bestValue[5];
                            if((depth + 3) % 2 == isAIWhite ? temp[4]->element->boardValue > bestValue[4] : temp[4]->element->boardValue < bestValue[4])
                                bestValue[4] = temp[4]->element->boardValue;
                            temp[4] = temp[4]->next;
                        }
                        temp[3]->element->boardValue = bestValue[4];
                        if((depth + 2) % 2 == isAIWhite ? temp[3]->element->boardValue > bestValue[3] : temp[3]->element->boardValue < bestValue[3])
                            bestValue[3] = temp[3]->element->boardValue;
                        temp[3] = temp[3]->next;
                    }


                    temp[2]->element->boardValue = bestValue[3];
                    if((depth + 1) % 2 == isAIWhite ? temp[2]->element->boardValue > bestValue[2] : temp[2]->element->boardValue < bestValue[2])
                        bestValue[2] = temp[2]->element->boardValue;
                    temp[2] = temp[2]->next;
                }
                temp[1]->element->boardValue = bestValue[2];
                if((depth) % 2 == isAIWhite ? temp[1]->element->boardValue > bestValue[1] : temp[1]->element->boardValue < bestValue[1])
                    bestValue[1] = temp[1]->element->boardValue;
                temp[1] = temp[1]->next;
            }
            temp[0]->element->boardValue = bestValue[1];
            if((depth - 1) % 2 == isAIWhite ? temp[0]->element->boardValue > bestValue[0] : temp[0]->element->boardValue < bestValue[0])
                bestValue[0] = temp[0]->element->boardValue;
            temp[0] = temp[0]->next;
        }


        if((depth - 1 ) % 2 == isAIWhite)
        {

            struct boardStateList* tempOut = malloc(sizeof(struct boardStateList));
            struct boardStateList* tempOutCopy = tempOut;   
            tempOut->next = currentBoard->children;


            while(tempOut->next)
            {
                if(tempOut->next->element->boardValue == bestValue[0])
                {
                    currentBoard = tempOut->next->element;
                    tempOut->next = tempOut->next->next;
                    break;
                }
                tempOut = tempOut->next;
            }

            free(tempOutCopy);

            killChildren(currentBoard->parent);

            printBoard(currentBoard->board); //aiutils.c:303
        }
        else
        {
            int sourceRow, sourceCol, destRow, destCol;
            printf("Source Row:");
            scanf("%d", &sourceRow);
            printf("Source Col:");
            scanf("%d", &sourceCol);
            printf("destRow:");
            scanf("%d", &destRow);
            printf("destCol:");
            scanf("%d", &destCol);

            struct boardStateList* tempOut = malloc(sizeof(struct boardStateList));
            struct boardStateList* tempOutCopy = tempOut;   
            tempOut->next = currentBoard->children;


            while(tempOut->next)
            {
                if(currentBoard->board[sourceRow * 8 + sourceCol] == tempOut->next->element->board[destRow * 8 + destCol])
                {
                    currentBoard = tempOut->next->element;
                    tempOut->next = tempOut->next->next;
                    break;
                }
                tempOut = tempOut->next;
            }

            if(!tempOut)
            {
                printf("No Move Found\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            free(tempOutCopy);

            killChildren(currentBoard->parent);

        }



}
```

this codes allocates memory for the boards

```
void addChildBoard(struct boardState* parent, int sourceRow, int sourceCol, int destRow, int destCol)
{
    //create new childboard and init values
    struct boardState* child = malloc(sizeof(struct boardState));
    if(!child)
        printf("OOM");
    child->parent = parent;
    child->children = 0;
    //add child to parent linked lisk
    struct boardStateList* current = parent->children;
    if(!current)
    {
        parent->children = malloc(sizeof(struct boardStateList));
        if(!parent->children)
            printf("OOM");  
        parent->children->element = child;
        parent->children->next = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        while((current->next))
            current = current->next;
        current->next = malloc(sizeof(struct boardStateList));
        if(!current->next)
            printf("OOM");
        current->next->element = child;
        current->next->next = 0;
    }
    //init child board to parent then make change
    //for(int i = 0;i < 64;i++)
    //  child->board[i] = parent->board[i];
    memcpy(child->board, parent->board, 64);
    child->board[destRow * 8 + destCol] = child->board[sourceRow * 8 + sourceCol];
    child->board[sourceRow * 8 + sourceCol] = 0;
}
```

this codes frees the memory

```
void killChildren(struct boardState* parent)
{
    struct boardStateList* temp[7];

    temp[0] = parent->children;
        while(temp[0])
        {
            temp[1] = temp[0]->element->children;
            while(temp[1])
            {
                temp[2] = temp[1]->element->children;
                while(temp[2])
                {
                    temp[3] = temp[2]->element->children;
                    while(temp[3])
                    {
                        temp[4] = temp[3]->element->children;
                        while(temp[4])
                        {
                            temp[5] = temp[4]->element->children;
                            while(temp[5])

                            {
                                free(temp[5]->element);
                                temp[6] = temp[5];
                                temp[5] = temp[5]->next;
                                free(temp[6]);
                            }

                            free(temp[4]->element);
                            temp[6] = temp[4];
                            temp[4] = temp[4]->next;
                            free(temp[6]);
                        }
                        free(temp[3]->element);
                        temp[6] = temp[3];
                        temp[3] = temp[3]->next;
                        free(temp[6]);
                    }


                    free(temp[2]->element);
                    temp[6] = temp[2];
                    temp[2] = temp[2]->next;
                    free(temp[6]);
                }
                free(temp[1]->element);
                temp[6] = temp[1];
                temp[1] = temp[1]->next;
                free(temp[6]);
            }
            free(temp[0]->element); //aiutils.c:742
            temp[6] = temp[0];
            temp[0] = temp[0]->next;
            free(temp[6]);
        }


}
```

When I try to read one of the output boards it is partially garbled and then the program segfaults. 
here is the output of valgrind

```
==3013== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3013== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3013== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3013== Command: ./chess white
==3013== Parent PID: 2898
==3013== 
--3013-- 
--3013-- Valgrind options:
--3013--    --leak-check=full
--3013--    --show-leak-kinds=all
--3013--    --track-origins=yes
--3013--    --verbose
--3013--    --log-file=valgrind-out.txt
--3013-- Contents of /proc/version:
--3013--   Linux version 4.14.123-111.109.amzn2.x86_64 (mockbuild@ip-10-0-1-12) (gcc version 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5) (GCC)) #1 SMP Mon Jun 10 19:37:57 UTC 2019
--3013-- 
--3013-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, LittleEndian, amd64-cx16-lzcnt-rdtscp-sse3-avx-avx2-bmi
--3013-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--3013-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib64/valgrind
--3013-- Reading syms from /home/ec2-user/chess-ai/chess
--3013-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/ld-2.26.so
--3013-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--3013--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--3013--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--3013-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--3013-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib64/valgrind/default.supp
==3013== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-3013-by-ec2-user-on-ip-172-31-14-154.ec2.internal
==3013== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-3013-by-ec2-user-on-ip-172-31-14-154.ec2.internal
==3013== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-3013-by-ec2-user-on-ip-172-31-14-154.ec2.internal
==3013== 
==3013== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==3013== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==3013== or are doing some strange experiment):
==3013==   /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=3013 ...command...
==3013== 
==3013== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==3013==   /path/to/gdb ./chess
==3013== and then give GDB the following command
==3013==   target remote | /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=3013
==3013== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==3013== 
--3013-- REDIR: 0x401cd20 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strlen) redirected to 0x5805bed1 (???)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x401cb00 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:index) redirected to 0x5805beeb (???)
--3013-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--3013-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
==3013== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--3013--     old: 0x0401cd20 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x5805bed1 ???
--3013--     new: 0x0401cd20 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x04c2fc50 strlen
--3013-- REDIR: 0x401ad90 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strcmp) redirected to 0x4c30d80 (strcmp)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x401d260 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:mempcpy) redirected to 0x4c34390 (mempcpy)
--3013-- Reading syms from /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebf9b0 (libc.so.6:memmove) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebebe0 (libc.so.6:strncpy) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebfc90 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebe630 (libc.so.6:strcat) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebec10 (libc.so.6:rindex) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ec1260 (libc.so.6:rawmemchr) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebfb20 (libc.so.6:mempcpy) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebf950 (libc.so.6:bcmp) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebeba0 (libc.so.6:strncmp) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebe6a0 (libc.so.6:strcmp) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebfa80 (libc.so.6:memset) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ed94c0 (libc.so.6:wcschr) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebeb40 (libc.so.6:strnlen) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebe710 (libc.so.6:strcspn) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebfce0 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebe6e0 (libc.so.6:strcpy) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebfe20 (libc.so.6:memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebec40 (libc.so.6:strpbrk) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebe660 (libc.so.6:index) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebeb10 (libc.so.6:strlen) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ec5b10 (libc.so.6:memrchr) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebfd30 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp_l) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebf920 (libc.so.6:memchr) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4eda280 (libc.so.6:wcslen) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebeef0 (libc.so.6:strspn) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebfc60 (libc.so.6:stpncpy) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebfc30 (libc.so.6:stpcpy) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ec1290 (libc.so.6:strchrnul) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebfd80 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp_l) redirected to 0x4a2771e (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4f8ebf0 (libc.so.6:__strrchr_avx2) redirected to 0x4c2f5d0 (rindex)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebaf00 (libc.so.6:malloc) redirected to 0x4c2cb0d (malloc)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4f8edc0 (libc.so.6:__strlen_avx2) redirected to 0x4c2fb90 (strlen)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4f8ea00 (libc.so.6:__strchrnul_avx2) redirected to 0x4c33ec0 (strchrnul)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4f8f2e0 (libc.so.6:__mempcpy_avx_unaligned_erms) redirected to 0x4c33fd0 (mempcpy)
--3013-- REDIR: 0x4ebb590 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c2dcba (free)
==3013== Invalid read of size 1
==3013==    at 0x404062: prinmtBoard (chessutils.c:254)
==3013==    by 0x403625: initDataSet (aiutils.c:303)
==3013==    by 0x4006EB: main (main.c:38)
==3013==  Address 0x51ef524 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 88 free'd
==3013==    at 0x4C2DD28: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==3013==    by 0x402604: killChildren (aiutils.c:742)
==3013==    by 0x403615: initDataSet (aiutils.c:301)
==3013==    by 0x4006EB: main (main.c:38)
==3013==  Block was alloc'd at
==3013==    at 0x4C2CB7B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==3013==    by 0x400988: addChildBoard (aiutils.c:657)
==3013==    by 0x400DA2: findPossiblePawnMoves (aiutils.c:472)
==3013==    by 0x402F6B: findPossibleMoves (aiutils.c:434)
==3013==    by 0x402F6B: initDataSet (aiutils.c:189)
==3013==    by 0x4006EB: main (main.c:38)
==3013== 
==3013== 
==3013== Process terminating with default action of signal 1 (SIGHUP)
==3013==    at 0x4F1F892: write (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so)
==3013==    by 0x4EB1D7C: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so)
==3013==    by 0x4EB105E: new_do_write (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so)
==3013==    by 0x4EB2F68: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so)
==3013==    by 0x4EB3011: _IO_file_underflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so)
==3013==    by 0x4EB41E1: _IO_default_uflow (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so)
==3013==    by 0x4E9503C: _IO_vfscanf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so)
==3013==    by 0x4EA3957: __isoc99_scanf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so)
==3013==    by 0x4026D3: nextMove (aiutils.c:24)
==3013==    by 0x4006F6: main (main.c:42)
==3013== 
==3013== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3013==     in use at exit: 104 bytes in 2 blocks
==3013==   total heap usage: 232,874,525 allocs, 232,874,523 frees, 12,109,477,208 bytes allocated
==3013== 
==3013== Searching for pointers to 2 not-freed blocks
==3013== Checked 69,400 bytes
==3013== 
==3013== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==3013==    at 0x4C2CB7B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==3013==    by 0x402670: nextMove (aiutils.c:15)
==3013==    by 0x4006F6: main (main.c:42)
==3013== 
==3013== 88 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==3013==    at 0x4C2CB7B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==3013==    by 0x4006DD: main (main.c:37)
==3013== 
==3013== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3013==    definitely lost: 88 bytes in 1 blocks
==3013==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3013==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3013==    still reachable: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==3013==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3013== 
==3013== ERROR SUMMARY: 65 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==3013== 
==3013== 64 errors in context 1 of 2:
==3013== Invalid read of size 1
==3013==    at 0x404062: printBoard (chessutils.c:254)
==3013==    by 0x403625: initDataSet (aiutils.c:303)
==3013==    by 0x4006EB: main (main.c:38)
==3013==  Address 0x51ef524 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 88 free'd
==3013==    at 0x4C2DD28: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==3013==    by 0x402604: killChildren (aiutils.c:742)
==3013==    by 0x403615: initDataSet (aiutils.c:301)
==3013==    by 0x4006EB: main (main.c:38)
==3013==  Block was alloc'd at
==3013==    at 0x4C2CB7B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==3013==    by 0x400988: addChildBoard (aiutils.c:657)
==3013==    by 0x400DA2: findPossiblePawnMoves (aiutils.c:472)
==3013==    by 0x402F6B: findPossibleMoves (aiutils.c:434)
==3013==    by 0x402F6B: initDataSet (aiutils.c:189)
==3013==    by 0x4006EB: main (main.c:38)
==3013== 
==3013== ERROR SUMMARY: 65 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

That code isn't something appealing to read x) but I'll show you how to use valgrind's output to find the problem yourself ;)

```
==3013== Invalid read of size 1
==3013==    at 0x404062: prinmtBoard (chessutils.c:254)
==3013==    by 0x403625: initDataSet (aiutils.c:303)
==3013==    by 0x4006EB: main (main.c:38)
==3013==  Address 0x51ef524 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 88 free'd
==3013==    at 0x4C2DD28: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:530)
==3013==    by 0x402604: killChildren (aiutils.c:742)
==3013==    by 0x403615: initDataSet (aiutils.c:301)
==3013==    by 0x4006EB: main (main.c:38)
==3013==  Block was alloc'd at
==3013==    at 0x4C2CB7B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==3013==    by 0x400988: addChildBoard (aiutils.c:657)
==3013==    by 0x400DA2: findPossiblePawnMoves (aiutils.c:472)
==3013==    by 0x402F6B: findPossibleMoves (aiutils.c:434)
==3013==    by 0x402F6B: initDataSet (aiutils.c:189)
==3013==    by 0x4006EB: main (main.c:38)
```

There are 3 details for 1 memory error here:

- the error is an invalid read of size 1, so you try to access a memory zone of 1 byte that is not (anymore) in YOUR memory. (happens on line 254 of chessutils.c:254)
- Adress xxx is 4 bytes inside of a block of 88 freed. That means the memory you are trying to access used to be yours, but isn't anymore cause you just free'd it, at line 742 of aiutils.c
- The memory block that you freed, then used, was malloced at line 657 of file aiutils.

This should normally be enough to follow the process of your code and find the bug, find that malloc, the place where you free it, and then any place where you still use that memory that does not belong to you anymore ;)

If after this you still crash, but the error changed, you probably progressed. Don't forget that a bug can always be hiddent by another one, this is even more true when it comes to memory debugging.

Best of luck o/

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to have a look at [clang's address sanitiser](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html), which is available under GNU/Linux.
It can help you to detect following type of bugs;

- Out-of-bounds accesses to heap, stack and globals
- Use-after-free
- Use-after-return (runtime flag ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_stack_use_after_return=1)
- Use-after-scope (clang flag -fsanitize-address-use-after-scope)
- Double-free, invalid free
- Memory leaks (experimental)